# Apex - First error: Update failed

Tags: apex, trigger

Have an apex batch code to update account totals from related list...account data.... recieiving this error....and some records updating appropriately, but not all. Code follows

> First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001d000001k8jDzAAI; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Trigger_Account: execution of BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with...

```
global without sharing class BatchAccountSalesDataRollup implements Database.Batchable<sobject>, Database.Stateful {

    public String strQuery = 'Select Id From Account Where Type != \'Parent\'  Order By CreatedDate DESC';
    public Set<Id> setAccountIds;
    
    public static Set<Id> accountIds;
    
    public static void runAccountSalesDataRollupForAccounts( Set<Id> setAccountIdVal ){

          String strQuery;
          BatchAccountSalesDataRollup clsAccountSalesDataRollup = new BatchAccountSalesDataRollup();
          clsAccountSalesDataRollup.setAccountIds = setAccountIdVal;
          clsAccountSalesDataRollup.strQuery =  ' Select Id From Account Where Type != \'Parent\' And Id in : setAccountIds '
                                              + ' Order By CreatedDate DESC ';

          id batchstart = Database.executeBatch(clsAccountSalesDataRollup,1);

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

        return Database.getQueryLocator(strQuery);
    }

    global void execute(Database.batchableContext bc, List<Account> listAccount ) {

        List<Sales_Data__c> listSalesdata = [ SELECT Id, GM__c, GMDollars__c, Margin_Sales_Dollars__c, Account__c,
                                                     Budget_Amount__c, Year__c, Period__c,
                                                     Actual_Amount__c, Forecast_Amount__c
                                              FROM Sales_Data__c
                                              Where Account__c in: listAccount
                                              Order By Account__c
                                             ]; 
        accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for( Account acc : listAccount ) {
            accountIds.add( acc.Id );   
        }

        /*AccountSalesDataRollup clsAccSalesRollup = new AccountSalesDataRollup(' Select Id Form Sales_Data__c ');
        AccountSalesDataRollup.executeCal = true;
        clsAccSalesRollup.calcualteAccountSalesDataRollup( listSalesdata );*/
        AccountSalesDataRollupAsFiscalYear clsAccSalesRollup = new AccountSalesDataRollupAsFiscalYear();
        //AccountSalesDataRollupClone.executeCal = true;
        clsAccSalesRollup.calcualteAccountSalesDataRollup(listSalesdata);

    }

    global void finish(Database.batchableContext bc){

        //AccountSalesDataRollup clsAccSalesRollup = new AccountSalesDataRollup(' Select Id Form Sales_Data__c ');
        AccountSalesDataRollupAsFiscalYear clsAccSalesRollup = new AccountSalesDataRollupAsFiscalYear();
        clsAccSalesRollup.finishActions(bc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you posted the rest of the error message? Seems you truncated the most important part. It does not seem that the code you posted is where the issue is since it is not a trigger